# Why is my alert not displaying the DIV I want it to display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

The following code sends an alert to the screen as 'undefined'. I would like to alert the `html` of `#div`.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageurl,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            alert($(data).children("#div").html());
        }       
    });
```

I could do something like in load, but I don't think I'm allowed:

```
    url: pageurl + ' #div'
```

How can I resolve this?

**UPDATE**: Based on advice from @Murali, I've tried the following, but it still doesn't behave as I would like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'index.html',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {                    
                alert($(data).find('#site-content').html());
            }
        });
});
  </script>

<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="site-content">
    some data</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the raw `data` string look like?

Comment: You mean, you want to take a particular portion of your response?

Comment: have you tried alerting your data

Comment: If you want to put the retrieved values finally into some other element, you can try using `$(selector).load(pageurl+' #div')`

Comment: @BenM raw data is a webpage <html><header>....

Comment: @Murali yes, thats right

Comment: @Abhilash that's what i did previously but the embedded javascript wasn't getting executed when using load.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can you not return the contents only of that div? Why get the whole html file?

Comment: is #div id of your div from which you have to get html

Comment: @Abhilash I could do that, but that means I'd have to edit every existing page for which this javascript uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

Change this

```
 $(data).children("#div").html()
```

To

```
 $(data).find('#yourDivId').html()
```

Note: yourDivId -> give the id of the div. In your code you mentioned as '#div' not sure whether really your code is like `<div id='div'>`

**Code i tried**

**in Index.html**

```
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'page.html',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {                    
                $(data).find('#site-content').html();
            }
        });
```

**In Page.html**

```
 <head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="site-content">
    some data</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that gives me the same result: undefined.

Comment: try alert $(data).length and see. If you dont see , then there is no HTML response from server

Comment: i get 83 --- i would have larger number though

Comment: Then you should get. What is the div id? Is div have id?

Comment: I am basically 'get'-ing a proper webpage, full webpage from which I would like to only take one specific div.

Comment: The div does have an id, yes. #content

Comment: Ok. Would you be able to share your complete working code please? Then I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway it works fine for me. Have no idea, what stops for you :(

Comment: See my updated answer. You are calling ajax and mixing html in same page. I used in different pages, i mean the ajax page should have that div id=site-content

Answer (score 0):

are you sure

```
$(data).children("#div")
```

return definded element?
try this:

```
String($(data).children("#div").html());
```

or try

```
console.log($(data).children("#div").html());
```

for reassured returned data is string and not empty.

Comment: No $(data).children("#div") does not return defined element. What I don't understand is that #div is definitely there though when I do alert(data) i can see. Maybe I'm getting confused between Strings and Jquery objects.

Comment: data must be string or json object for jquery selector. data can be "#parent-id" and your html must be "<div id="parent-id"><div id "div"></div></div>" to return true